# C# : How to create a constructor with DateTime as parameter? and how to create an object with this constructor?

Tags: c#, datetime, object, parameters, constructor

I have created a constructor as follows :

```
public Animal(string regNum, DateTime brought, string name)
{
    this.RegNumber = regNum;
    this.DateBrought = brought;
    this.Name = name;
    this.NameNewOwner = null;
}
```

And based on the constructor above, I created an object called `pet`, as follows:

```
Animal pet = new Animal("a12344", Convert.ToDateTime(23/01/2013), "Fluffy");
```

However, when I run my program it gives me error saying: `Invalid cast from Int32 to DateTime` Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `Convert.ToDateTime("23/01/2013")`?  Note the quotation marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructor is not a problem. `Convert.ToDateTime` call is:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(23 / 01 / 2013);
```

It's equivalent to `Convert.ToDateTime(0)` (because `23/1/2013` as integer division returns `0`), which is not possible.

Use `new DateTime(2013, 1, 23)` instead.

```
Animal pet = new Animal("a12344", new DateTime(2013, 1, 23), "Fluffy");
```

You could also use `Convert.ToDateTime("23/01/2013")`, which would be equivalent to `DateTime.Parse("21/01/2013")` parsing, but if you know the date at compile time, you should definitely use `DateTime` constructor.